# why do jQuery.merge set the length of return value by hand?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading the source code of jQuery. In the function of jQuery.merge

```
    merge: function( first, second ) {
    var i = first.length,
        j = 0;

    if ( typeof second.length === "number" ) {
        for ( var l = second.length; j < l; j++ ) {
            first[ i++ ] = second[ j ];
        }

    } else {
        while ( second[j] !== undefined ) {
            first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
        }
    }

    first.length = i;

    return first;
}
```

There are two things I cannot understand:

1. Why it checked the type of second.length, but not check the type of first.length?
2. Since the length of Array is increased automatically, why do we need to set the length by hand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not have, and does not support Associative Arrays. However… All arrays in Javascript are objects and Javascript's object syntax gives a basic emulation of an associative Array.

So, if you were to run:

```
 x = [];
 x['a'] = 1;
 x['b'] = 2;
 alert(x.length); //alerts 0;
```

So they set length to allow us to get the length that we expect

Comment: I tried to merge an Array to a Associative-array, but the length of result equals the length of Array. Besides, I don't think Merge can handle associative-arrays, because there's another function "extend" is designed to do that job.